# Translating a page with jquery "translator", google translate etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, translation, google-widget

I've encountered a serious (as for me) problem, the thing is that I have a stylized dropdown menu with 2 options, those options are Polish and English languages(Polish is the default one), what i want is: when selecting other language (so far only English) the whole page must be translated, I tried google widget, but stylizing that widget is a real pain in a... head? tried jQuery translator, but it has way too much problems as for now AND prefered way to translate my web-page is by using google widget, has anyone encountered such problems and succeded to solve them ?

Comment: @Java_User I'll have access to that code in 12 hours from now :(
but why do you need it anyway ?

Comment: Need to know what all you have tried. Its often easy to debug looking at the code.

Comment: @Java_User the code for jQuery translator is already erased, because I've even asked my older colleague to help me out, but he failed as well, maybe too tired by the end of the day -_- as for the widget, nothing special, it works ok, but it's almost impossible to stylize it in a way I need it to look like

Comment: @Java_User there is no code
i am using this widget to translate the page
https://translate.google.com/manager/website/suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Google's Website Translator](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/)? They have pretty much done all the work for you, so you don't have to re-invent the wheel

Comment: i tried that one, and if you read my post carefully, you would notice that google translate widget is almost impossible to stylize, i don't want that creepy bar on my website